# ListData.svc REST issue in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, rest

Im having a big problem in Sharepoint 2010. Im already thinking its a bug in the product.

I need to search two Form Libraries, one in a site in English, and the other in a site in Portuguese, with the ListData.svc REST service.

The problem lies when i try to filter the Form Library by the ContentType. In the english Library, it all goes well, but in the portuguese one, ContentType is spelled "TipoDeConteúdo", which I think is breaking it because of the special char.

Here are the urls

English: http://pc55861/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Consultas?$filter=ContentType eq 'ConsultaJuridico'
Portuguese: http://pc55861:81/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/Consultas?$filter=TipoDeConteúdo eq 'ConsultaJuridico'

I already tried to use "ContentType" instead of "TipoDeConteúdo", to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you've found the answer by now, but since this question doesn't have an answer, here it goes:

When you query a non-English site with the REST service you need to provide the display names of lists and fields, like this:

```
var url = "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Páginas?$filter=" + encodeURIComponent('TipoDeConteúdo') + " eq 'News Article'"
```

In the querystring portion of the url (filter, sort, etc) you need to URLencode all the special charecters like in the example above.

Comment: i second your suggestion. I just wanted to confirm where you took the encodeURIComponent method from or was it pseudo-language?

Comment: @zaitsman `encodeURIComponent` is a built-in function in JavaScript. In other platforms you would of course need some other, similar function.